# Which kinds of codes have their automorphism group in the Clifford Group

Tags: error-correction

Two quantum codes are said to be equivalent if they are related by a non-entangling gate. The automorphism group of a quantum code is the group of all code equivalences.

Every automorphism of a $GF(4)$-linear code lies in the Clifford group (Cor 16 of [Quantum Codes of Minimum Distance Two](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/9704043.pdf)). We might think such a property is restricted to stabilizer codes but Cor 18 shows that the $((5,6,2))$ non-additive code also has its automorphisms in the Clifford group.

On the other hand, not every code has this property, for example, the $[[2,0,2]]$ Bell-state code has its automorphism group as $PSU(2) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_2$.

What is the largest "class" of quantum codes that have their automorphism group in the Clifford group?